# Does anybody know how to obtain the confidence intervals of a polychoric and tetrachoric correlations in R

Tags: correlation, confidence-interval, psych

I tried with John Fox's "polycor" package, but it does not show the ICs. I have also tried with the "psych" package but nothing. The only thing I got are the standard errors and the thresholds. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try the cor.ci function in psych.  This will find the confidence intervals by bootstrapping.

In addition, cor.plot.upperLowerCi will then display a correlation plot showing the upper and lower confidence values.

```
p.c <-cor.ci(bfi[1:200,1:5], poly = TRUE)
 cor.plot.upperLowerCi(p.c, numbers=TRUE)
```